# store Audio files in SdCard

Tags: android, listview, save, storage, recorder

Here is my call recording app code store Audio File in internal storage but i Want to Store Audio Files in External Storage. What i will change and files store in Sdcard

*I am making recording application that store audio files in storage*

```
 public void recordVoiceCall(String phNumber, String name, String type) {

    File LastingSalesRecordingsDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            audioFileDirectoryPath);


    if (!LastingSalesRecordingsDir.exists()) {
        LastingSalesRecordingsDir.mkdirs();
    }

    file_name = "call_" + MyDateTimeStamp.getCurrentDate() + "_" +
            MyDateTimeStamp.getCurrentTimeForFile() + "_" + type + "_" + phNumber + "_";
    try {
        audioFile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".mp3", LastingSalesRecordingsDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        file_name = audioFile.getName();

        if (recorder == null) {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);

            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());

            Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording output formats set.");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording Exception: " + e);
    }
    try {

        recorder.prepare();
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording Recorder prepared.");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        deleteVoiceFile(file_name);
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording prepare IllegalStateException: " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        deleteVoiceFile(file_name);
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording prepare IOException: " + e);
    }

    try {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
            throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
        }

        recorder.start();
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording Recorder started for: " + phNumber);
        recordStarted = true;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        deleteVoiceFile(file_name);
        Log.d(MyLogTags.recording, "Recording start Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. That is already external memory. Not the SD card. The only thing you need is a File object or file path to the SD card.  Once you have that the rest of your code is the same. You should also realise that on modern Android devices your app cannot write to a SD card. Only read. I do not know if the media audio recorder can write there.

Comment: @greenapps Is it possible to store audio recording files in external sdcard storage?

Comment: @greenapps I'm making Android recording Application and write same code, it will store data in internal memory but not in SdCard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android's default external storage directory to save your audio files.

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
```

You can also use File Class Constructor to create a new folder on SD card.

```
File audioFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
"newaudiofolder")
  if (!audioFolder.exists()) {
boolean success = audioFolder.mkdir()
if (success) {
    // save the file 
}
}
```

Make sure to add permission in Manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```